# How to retrieve connected values from relationship table

Tags: mysql, sql, hana

I have two tables, one table(table 1) has certain set of values and other table(table 2) contains, how these values are connected(basically relationship). Here, I am trying to retrieve the connected values from table 2.

Table 1 has following fields:

`ID| ROUTE | DIRECTION`
`A      335        IND`
`B      335        FRA` 
`C      770        MUM`
`D      770        MAD`
`E      5510       LON`
`E      5510       LON`

Table 2 as below

`R_ID| SOURCE | TARGET`
`1   A     C`
`2   A     B`
`3   B     D`
`4   E     F`
`5   F     G`
`6   F     H`

I am trying to query all connection of A from table2 joining table1, i.e, A-C,A-B-D. The query should retrieve values until target value is not in source field. Here, in this example query result should include until D.
I am expecting the result set to look like:

`ID| ROUTE | DIRECTION`
`A      335        IND`
`C      770        MUM`
`B      335        FRA` 
`D      770        MAD`

Comment: The simplest method is a recursive CTE, which is supported in MySQL 8+.

Comment: please indicate what version of HANA you use. With HANA2 hierarchy SQL functions are available that provide graph traversal.

Comment: SAP HANA2 version